# MS Graph Beta API doesn't get full sign in logs using python and stops seeming randomly?

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

We are trying to get the full signin logs using the following MS Graph Beta API request using Python (`/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=signInEventTypes/any(t: t eq 'servicePrincipal')`). According to Microsoft Documentation signin logs for the last 30 days are saved. Since only a certain amount of entries can be retrieved at once (1000 entries), we are using paging to get the next page using the link given in `@odata.nextLink`.

But here is the problem, it seems random how many pages the graph API retrieves after executing the code. Executing the same request after each other, it some times gives out around 50 pages, 70 pages and other times more or even less pages. It seems random how many pages are retrieved. Even filtering for days using for example `createdDateTime ge 2021-02-25 and createdDateTime le 2021-02-27`, it doesn't retrieve the whole logs for these two days. It also stops somewhere in the middle and it seems random how many pages it retrieves.

Another interesting issue is that during execution of the code, it sometimes doesn't retrieve the full 1000 entries for a page. For example on the first page 1000 entries are retrieved, for the second page only 978 entries and for the third page 1000 entries again. I don't quite understand why these issues arises but we can't reliably retrieve logs for certain timeframes. Anybody has a solution or know why it stops seeming randomly?

```
import os
import datetime
import json
import pandas as pd
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient, APIVersion

load_dotenv()

tenant_id = os.getenv("AZURE_TENANT_ID")
client_id = os.getenv("AZURE_CLIENT_ID")
client_secret = os.getenv("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET")

browser_credential=ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
client=GraphClient(credential=browser_credential, api_version=APIVersion.beta)

def get_signins_info(signin_data, signin_df):
'''
Fill dataframe with signins data
signin_data:
signin_df:
'''
id_ = signin_data["id"]
app_id = signin_data["appId"]
signin = signin_data["createdDateTime"]
    
row = {"id": id_, \
       "app_id": app_id, \
       "signin": signin, \
      }

signin_df = signins_df.append(row, ignore_index=True)

return signins_df

signins_df =  pd.DataFrame(columns=["objectId","appDisplayName","appId","activity"])  
next_link = "/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=signInEventTypes/any(t: t eq 'servicePrincipal')&(createdDateTime ge 2021-02-25 and createdDateTime le 2021-02-27)"

 while next_link:  
    result = client.get(next_link)  
    json_data = result.json()  
    if "value" in json_data:  
        for log in json_data["value"]:  
            signins_df = get_signins_info(log, signins_df)  
    if "@odata.nextLink" in json_data:  
        next_link = json_data["@odata.nextLink"]  
    else:  
        next_link = False 
    print(len(signins_df))
```

Comment: please provide sufficient code to replicate the error. For example, what does the user function `get_signins_info(log, signins_df)` do in order to provide its return to the visable part f the code ?

Comment: I have updated the post. It writes information like appid and when the entry was created in a padas dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the additional part.  First comment is that `df.append()` is depreciated and replaced with `df.concat`. Please see here https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Comment: next question.  what does `client.get()` do?  please provide code.

Comment: thanks for the input, I changed accordingly. client.get() makes a request to the graph api. It's based on GraphClient

Comment: you are welcome. Given the code, I would first check that this function is returning the links that you expect. (ie. you code is good to the point of this function).

Comment: It does return a page with normally 1000 entries in json and a `"@odata.nextLink"` with a link to the next page. The python script should get the this link until there is no next link anymore. It seem to work and the entries in the dataframe are correct. But the strange thing the number of pages it retrieves is random, even when I specify the timeframe.

Comment: You are not alone, I am facing the same issue collecting the logs via REST on PowerShell. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Added a sleep to check for throttling issues - doesn't appear to be helping.  Asking over on the Azure Discord.

Comment: Essentially I see this as a bug where it fails to return a ``$NextLink`` on the Response.  I'm trying to work around it by storing the last NextLink as another variable (``$LastLink``), and if the ``$NextLink`` is Null, using the ``$LastLink`` to collect the data again in the hope that ``$NextLink`` is included this time.

Comment: Follow Up: I have contacted MS Support. It seems to be a bug and shall be fixed with 01/04.

Comment: Thanks @AzUser1, to clarify "fixed with 01/04", did you mean 'fixed on the 1st April'?

Comment: yes, it should be fixed by now according to MS Support but I didn'have time to try it out yet. Does it work now for you?

Comment: Yes, confirmed working